# None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application. Exit status 222

Tags: ibm-cloud

I developed a Node.js app in the Bluemix Web IDE and deployed it some time before, it is running on Bluemix currently just fine.

However, when I tried to deploy it today after a 2 minor changes:

1. created new branch
2. created new .jade file, edited this and another
   .jade file no code or config change

I got the error

```
    Updated app with guid 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb ({"name"=>"ACP", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "instances"=>1, "memory"=>1024, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
    Updated app with guid 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb ({"route"=>"8e8a376d-479e-4b4f-921e-932e40fd569f"})
    Updated app with guid 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb ({"console"=>true, "state"=>"STOPPED"})
    Updated app with guid 998e32e6-3f4f-4743-8e36-f8cd4c0961bb ({"console"=>true, "state"=>"STARTED"})
    Downloading liberty-for-java_v3_6-20161209-1351...
...
    Downloaded python_buildpack
    Creating container
    Successfully created container
    Downloading app package...
    Downloaded app package (6.6M)
    Staging...
    None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application
    Exit status 222
    Destroying container
    Failed to stage application: staging failed
    Successfully destroyed container
```

Seems like the error is described here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/detection.html

What am I supposed to do exactly in Bluemix Web IDE?

Comment: What was this "minor change"?

Comment: I tried it again and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. created new branch
2. created new .jade file, edited this and another .jade file

no code or config change